# Hive Column Value is getting replaced by current date when importing it to CSV

Tags: bash, shell, hive, hiveql

I have hive column named **Date_of_Birth** when we dont have any values for this column we populate it with

> ' '

(two single quotes), when we query it in hive shell it displays proper result but when we are exporting it CSV using shell script its getting replaced with current timestamp.

Below is example 
In hive shell

> Select Date_of_birth from Details where id=1;

Result is

> '  '

Where as when I ran this for CSV export the value for the corresponding column comes as

> **2018-06-28 05:43:23**

Any idea how why it is behaving like that?